# How to draw rectangle with 1px border using html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I don't know why that white point appear at the bottom right corner of the created rectangle.
(Only visible in 21.0.1180.83 and .89 under WinXP)

It depends on the canvas height...

http://jsbin.com/ejeyef/1/

[image: dot]

Comment: The white point is not visible in firefox 15.0

Comment: The white point is not visible in Chromium 18.0.1025.168 (Developer Build 134367 Linux) Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: White point not visible in Chrome 21.0.1180.82 on OS X 10.8.1

Comment: looks fine in my browser (Opera 12.02 on Windows 7). Seems like you found a browser-specific bug.

Comment: Is visible under Chrome 21.0.1180.83 m on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

It probably has something to do with [Subpixel rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) . Looking at your code, you do the following:

```
c.rect(10.5, 10.5, 100, 100);
```

Which means: "Draw a rectangle, with a size of 100x100px at the coordinates 10.5px from X, and 10.5px from Y". The screen/browser can't render a "half pixel", so it's always rounded somewhere. That might be the cause of your problem.

To fix this, simply don't use half values for this kind of things. This works fine:

```
c.rect(10, 10, 100, 100);
```

Comment: than the rectangle will be ugly.

Comment: That has to do [with this](https://www.lucidchart.com/threads/view/5557) (and - as stated there - isn't a bug).

Comment: @MarcoK using float coordinates is a widely accepted method of drawing on the HTML5 Canvas without the blur.